# постраничный 301 редирект

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

есть старый сайт его нужно редиректнуть на обновленный сайт (на WP) с другим доменом. Главная страница старого сайт старыйсайт.com/index.php редиректится на главную нового новыйсайт.com, проблема в том что остальные страницы редиректятся не понятно на что, пример старыйсайт.com/index.php?show_aux_page=1(страница с контактами) редиректится на новыйсайт.com/index.php?show_aux_page=1, который в свою очередь копия главной страницы нового сайта. Первое, что это за параметры (/index.php?show_aux_page=1, /index.php?show_aux_page=20 и тд.). Второе, как сделать чтобы эти страницы (старыйсайт.com/index.php?show_aux_page=1 переходил на новыйсайт.com/contacts/ и тд). Вот что писал в .htaccess(не только это, разный варианты пробовал, это последнее, что писал):

для главной:

Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.site.com/newpage.html

для страниц с параметрами:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^limitstart=0

RewriteRule ^blog http://site.ru/blog? [R=301,L]

Comment: Ничего не понял из вопроса. Что куда надо перенаправлять? В чем проблема?

Comment: проще говоря, все страницы со старого сайта на новый, но некоторые страницы имеют параметры типа show_aux_page=1, и нужно чтобы они (параметры ) исчезали при перенаправлении